# Gray pixels in YouTube video

Tags: youtube, video

I have posted a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oRwKhYMBvo) and it begins with many gray pixels (squares).

What can I do?

See this print-screen too:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6YKW.jpg]

Comment: The problem is in the video; I can see the gray pixels too, but it only appears @ 0:02.

Comment: I don't think. On computer the gray pixels don't appear...

Comment: @John, you are not watching the YouTube video on your computer, you are watching the original video. The one on YouTube is a *converted* copy of your video, and obviously something went wrong during the conversion. Try deleting the video and uploading (the original) again. If that still doesn’t work, try converting it on your own computer and uploading the converted version to YouTube.

Comment: I agree, @Synetech, but I am not sure if this is a problem of my video format (wmv) or is a youtube/flash player bug. PS: if you will post an answer, I will be happy to vote it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube [officially supports WMV files](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55744), and the Flash Player seems to work for most videos, so the video corruption is likely due to a bug during the conversion from your original WMV video to the MP4 that YouTube stores on its servers (it may even be as little as one corrupt frame).

You should try uploading the original again to see if conversion will work the second time.

If it does not, you can try converting the video to MP4 yourself. [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) is a popular and easy-to-use program for this. The dimensions of the video [should not matter](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/make-720p-hd-widescreen-screencasts-for-youtube/8031/), so you don’t have to worry about re-sizing or anything. Just convert it to MP4 yourself (which gives you greater control over the quality) and YouTube may not even convert the it at all.

They also have [some tips](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en-GB&guide=1728585&topic=1728569&page=guide.cs) for uploading videos that may help. If all else fails, you can use the *Report a bug* link at the [bottom of the page](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oRwKhYMBvo#footer-container) or contact them about it (the contact page says *AV sync* issues, but the [page](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=55744) that links to it does not: *If you continue to experience Audio/Video issues with your upload, [contact us](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/request.py?&contact_type=avsync) and we may be able to help.*)

Comment: I agree. Thank you for your answer. I think that I had the same problem a long time ago, but it was fixed automatic. Do you think that they keep the original video, and they can fix it without re-uploading? I uploaded it first as private video and watched it. No problems. I hope that they will fix it.

Comment: I doubt that they keep the original; they probably only keep a high-quality MP4 version.

Comment: YouTube will always convert a video when you upload it, no matter what format.

Comment: Then hopefully it will do a better job converting from H.264 or XviD than from WMV.